# Javascript is rendered incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

So, I'm working with JSF 2.0, and I've created a javascript that looks like this:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    function generate(){
                        if(!licenseServerInfo){
                            NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.warning,['<strong>Your changes to License Server Name and Computer ID have not been saved.</strong><a href="" class="right"><strong>Undo Change</strong></a>'],NI.pnx.messaging.messageTimeoutSpeeds.never);
                        }else{
                            generateLicenseFile();
                            document.getElementById('upperButtons:generateCall').click();
                        }
                    }                   
            </script>
```

But it's rendered like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

                    function generate(){
                        if(!licenseServerInfo){
                            NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.warning,['<strong>Your changes to License Server Name and Computer ID have not been saved.
//--></strong><a class="right"><strong>Undo Change<!--

                    function generate(){
                        if(!licenseServerInfo){
                            NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.warning,['<strong>Your changes to License Server Name and Computer ID have not been saved.
//--></strong><!--

                    function generate(){
                        if(!licenseServerInfo){
                            NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.warning,['<strong>Your changes to License Server Name and Computer ID have not been saved.
//--></a>'],NI.pnx.messaging.messageTimeoutSpeeds.never);
                        }else{
                            generateLicenseFile();
                            document.getElementById('upperButtons:generateCall').click();
                        }
                    }

                <!--

                    function generate(){
                        if(!licenseServerInfo){
                            NI.pnx.messaging.popMessage(NI.pnx.messaging.messageTypes.warning,['<strong>Your changes to License Server Name and Computer ID have not been saved.
//--></script>
```

Using chrome's console, if I call each of the contained functions, they all work right. But if I try to call generate(), it says it doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: on one hand, it looks you're generating that code inside a loop (that's why the function is being written multiple times), on the other hand you could try setting your script inside a <![CDATA[ ]]> to avoid the browser trying to parse it

Comment: The CDATA did it. Feel free to leave that as an answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, it looks you're generating that code inside a loop (that's why the function is being written multiple times). On the other hand you could try setting your script inside a `<![CDATA[ ]]>` to avoid the browser trying to parse it